# How to change the font for predefined key terms for academic papers in LaTex?

Tags: fonts, formatting, ieeeconf

I have searched quite a lot on the Internet for how to change the font type for certain predefined terms in academic papers. For example, a Windows 'System32' folder will be in a different font than the rest of the document. Something about the font conveys that it is a particular "name" for something specific. It is hard to explain but this paper demonstrates it:

[image]

Notice how names like 'Gpcode' and 'Tobfy' are a different font in this Springer paper? How do I do that in LaTex in the Springer LNCS journal format or IEEE format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\texttt{Gpcode}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a macro called `\keyterm` in the preamble

```
\newcommand\keyterm[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

and type

```
... the community (e.g., \keyterm{Gpcode}, \keyterm{Reveton}). The remaining ...
```

in the body of the text.

With this setup, if you decide later on that key terms should be typeset using the bold-italic version of the main text font instead of a teletype (aka, monospaced) font, all you'll need to do is change the definition of `\keyterm` to

```
\newcommand\keyterm[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

and recompile the document.